# Regular Expression pattern seems to not work in Adobe Experience Manager filter exclusion rule

Tags: aem

I'm using Adobe Experience Manager version 6 and I'm having a difficulty excluding `.DS_Store` files from my packages.

I modified my `META-INF/vault/filter.xml` file to exclude the file name pattern:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/apps/myapp">
        <exclude pattern="\.DS_Store"/>
    </filter>
</workspaceFilter>
```

But when I upload my packages or push them via vlt the `.DS_Store` file is still included.

I did some experimenting creating a package with a filter and exclusion rule via CRXDE Lite, but it confused me even more.

When I use the original filter with the exclusion rule and check the coverage, the `.DS_Store` files are still included:

[image: files are not excluded]

But when I create *this* filter with exclusion rule and check the coverage, the `.DS_Store` files *are* excluded:

[image: files are excluded]

Is there a reason why striking the dot in front of DS_Store doesn't work in the exclusion but using a 0 or more pattern does?

Answer (score 1):

Your first regular expression (.DS_Store), which isn't working, is looking for a node located at .DS_Store and the file is probably located at /.DS_Store.  The regular expression needs to match the full path.  The reason your second example (.*DS_Store) is working is because it's looking for 0 or more of any character before DS_Store.  That obviously matches any path that ends in DS_Store.

You can try out your examples on http://www.regexr.com/ and add some of your file paths in the text area to see how it's matching.

Instead of trying to use the filter.xml to exclude the files you may just exclude them using the maven-assembler-plugin in your build.

In your pom.xml you would add the plugin like this:

```
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

In the zip.xml you would specify something like the following which excludes files you don't want included in your package:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><assembly
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<id>zip</id>
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/content/jcr_root</directory>
        <outputDirectory>jcr_root</outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/.DS_Store</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <filtered>false</filtered>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/content/META-INF</directory>
        <outputDirectory>META-INF</outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/.DS_Store</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <filtered>true</filtered>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>jcr_root/apps/myapp/install</outputDirectory>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <includes>
            <include>com.icfolson.aem:myapp-core</include>
        </includes>
        <useStrictFiltering>true</useStrictFiltering>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```